# How to know when a controller unload in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, navigation

In my iOS application I have a login page that leads to the main pages. You can navigate between these pages with a tab bar. On each of these pages you can log out and return to the login page using the dismiss function. I wanted to know if by doing this I was leaving some controllers in a vacuum without having unloaded them.

For example, if I log in, go to the second tab and log out, will the first tab be unloaded?
And more broadly how does navigation with a tab bar work if it's not a stack?

Answer (score 0):

On successfull login change root of application to TabBarController.When user kill application and launch again then set root according to the login status of a user. And when user logout from application then again change root to login controller.

[Please check attached link](https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/)